# generate a delegate for a Button-Click Event

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates

I simply want to create a list of Buttons. But each button should do something different.

Its just for training. I'm new to `C#`.

what I have right now:

```
for (int i = 0; i < answerList.Count; i++)
{
     Button acceptButton = new Button { Content = "Lösung" };
     acceptButton.Click += anonymousClickFunction(i);
     someList.Items.Add(acceptButton);
}
```

I want to generate the `Click-Function` like this:

```
private Func<Object, RoutedEventArgs> anonymousClickFunction(i) { 
    return delegate(Object o, RoutedEventArgs e)
            { 
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(i.toString()); 
            };
}

/// (as you might see i made a lot of JavaScript before ;-))
```

I know that a delegate is not a Func... but I don't know what I have to do here.

But this is not working.

Do you have any suggestions how i can do something like this?

---

EDIT: Solution

I was blind ... didn't thought about creating a RoutedEventHandler :-)

```
private RoutedEventHandler anonymousClickFunction(int id) { 
        return new RoutedEventHandler(delegate(Object o, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {  
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(id.ToString()); 
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want an array of functions, and you want to get the function by index?

```
var clickActions = new RoutedEventHandler[]
{
       (o, e) =>
           {
               // index 0
           },

       (o, e) =>
           {
               // index 1
           },

       (o, e) =>
           {
               // index 2
           },
};

for (int i = 0; i < clickActions.Length; i++)
{
    Button acceptButton = new Button { Content = "Lösung" };
    acceptButton.Click += clickActions[i];
    someList.Items.Add(acceptButton);
}
```

Comment: i just tried to assign an anonymous delegate to an Click (But i forgot to wrap it in an RoutedEventHandler). But your solution is also possible. Thanks :-)

Comment: yes you're right, the correct type is RoutedEventHandler, but the compiler will accept a lambda expression of the same signature. Edited answer to be more correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, what you could do. Is the following, plain and simple.

```
for (int i = 0; i < answerList.Count; i++)
{
    var acceptButton = new Button { Content = "Lösung" };
    acceptButton.Click += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
    someList.Items.Add(acceptButton);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use lambda expressions for anonymous methods:

```
for (int i = 0; i < answerList.Count; i++)
{
     Button acceptButton = new Button { Content = "Lösung" };
     acceptButton.Click += (sender, args) => System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(i.toString());
     someList.Items.Add(acceptButton);
}
```